# How do I can get the data from a web page with Python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, web, scrapy

I made a code where I got the data from a web page. My problem is that I could only get the first page of the site and it has over than 40 tabs. How can I take the others pages?

I tried use for to take the others pages, but it doesn't work. I expected to get 1.406 registers but it's only returning 37 (All the data from first page)

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from csv import writer


url = "https://www.vivareal.com.br/venda/sp/sao-bernardo-do-campo/condominio_residencial/"
page = requests.get(url)
print(page)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
lists = soup.find_all('article', class_="property-card__container js-property-card")

with open('test.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
    thewriter = writer(f)
    header = ['Title', 'Location', 'Price', 'Area']
    thewriter.writerow(header)

    for list in lists:
        title = list.find('span', class_="js-card-title").text.replace('\n', '')
        location = list.find('span', class_="property-card__address").text.replace('\n', '')
        price = list.find('div', class_="js-property-card__price-small").text.replace('\n', '')
        area = list.find('span', class_="js-property-card-detail-area").text.replace('\n', '')

        info = [title, location, price, area]
        thewriter.writerow(info)
```

Comment: PLEASE do not include images of code.  Instead, cut-and-paste the code into your question.

Comment: You will have to examine the HTML to figure out what happens when you click a new tab.  If that triggers a new request with a page number or tab number, you can simulate that request.  If it's handled in Javascript, then you'll need to use something that interprets Javascript, like Selenium.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ok, Tim! This was my first publication here and I had no idea how to do it. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks about It! I'll keep trying figure out!

Answer (score 1):

Get HTML of next page's link in `lists` before extracting data from it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't have knowledge enough of it, but a tryied thid once and I didn't find the link. I don't know if is because I don't know where find it or if there isn't a link to another tab. I think it's the second.